# Fill missing dates in data frame where each column is a different date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame where each column is a different date, and some dates are missing.
I want to create new columns with the missing dates where each new column contains zeros.

I know how to do this when dates are an index, but I don't know how to do it when they are columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following example captures your use case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2021-09-01': [1, 2], 
                   '2021-09-02': [3, 4],
                   '2021-09-05': [5, 6]})
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df

   2021-09-01  2021-09-02  2021-09-05
0           1           3           5
1           2           4           6
```

Build an index of regularly spaced dates:

```
idx = pd.date_range(df.columns.min(), df.columns.max(), freq='d')
```

Reindex columns and fill missing values with 0:

```
df.reindex(columns=idx, fill_value=0)
df

   2021-09-01  2021-09-02  2021-09-03  2021-09-04  2021-09-05
0           1           3           0           0           5
1           2           4           0           0           6
```